# Can I call DOM event handling an instance of observable/observer pattern

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern, dom

In the following DOM event handling example (using jQuery):

```
$('#shopping-cart').on('click', function(event){...});
```

could I not call the shopping-cart DOM element the observable, and the function the observer? There is no "general" click event being hooked to, but a click event specific to the shopping-cart object itself.

The javascript example of observable/observer example I'm operating from is the following (taken from [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/fundamental-node-js-design-patterns/)):

```
// MyFancyObservable.js
var util = require('util');  
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
function MyFancyObservable() {  
  EventEmitter.call(this);
}
util.inherits(MyFancyObservable, EventEmitter);
MyFancyObservable.prototype.hello = function (name) {  
  this.emit('hello', name);
};


var MyFancyObservable = require('MyFancyObservable');  
var observable = new MyFancyObservable();
observable.on('hello', function (name) {  
  console.log(name);
});
observable.hello('john');
```

Notice that in the MyFancyObservable example, the `on('hello', function)` looks *exactly* like DOM event registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in the purpose of the Event.

In your Shopping Cart example, the event gets fired *in response to a **user action.***

In an Observable, the event gets fired [*in response to a **state change.***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Are they both examples of Event Handling? **Yes.**

Are they both Observers?  **No.**